# Using NHibernate with SQL Server Application Roles

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent

I'm using NHibernate (Fluently) to interact with a database that's locked down to all but an application role.

I'm able to use the application role within SQL Server Management Studio using the stored procs: **sp_setapprole** and **sp_unsetapprole** directly but I run into issues when attempting to do this with NHibernate:

```
using (var session = SessionFactory.OpenSession())
{
    byte[] cookie;

    // 1) Set the application role
    using (var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "sp_setapprole";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@rolename", RoleName));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", RolePassword));
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@fCreateCookie", true));
        command.Parameters.Add(
            new SqlParameter
                {
                    ParameterName = "@cookie",
                    DbType = DbType.Binary,
                    Direction = ParameterDirection.Output,
                    Size = 8000
                });

        // This works perfectly fine
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        var outVal = (SqlParameter)command.Parameters["@cookie"];

        // This returns a byte array value for the cookie generated
        cookie = (byte[])outVal.Value;
    }

    // 2) This line dutifully retreives my contrived Person object but renders
    //    part 3) of this saga next to useless because it performs a logout
    //    (identified with SQL Profiler) and the app role/cookie is forgotten.
    session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Person)).List<Person>().FirstOrDefault();

    // 3) Unset the application role
    using (var command = session.Connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "sp_unsetapprole";
        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@cookie", cookie));
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

So to summarise, doing anything between 1) and 3) in the above example causes the application to crash.  In two different ways depending on whether I'm Pooling or not:

**Pooling** - *A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.*

**Not pooling** - *Cannot unset application role because none was set or the cookie is invalid.*

I'm not sure if this helps, but I'm connecting with the following (would normally be be done slightly differently but I needed to configure the Pooling attribute):

```
private static ISessionFactory CreateSessionFactory()
{
    return Fluently.Configure().Database(
        MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.ConnectionString(
            "Data Source=(local);" +
            "Initial Catalog=PeopleDB;" +
            "Integrated Security=False;" +
            "User ID=someuserid;" +
            "Password=somepassword" +
            "Pooling=False"))
        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssemblyOf<Program>())
        .BuildSessionFactory();
}
```

FYI the user connecting in the above code has absolutely no permissions to the database, which does at least prove at the sp_setapprole is working.

Has anyone encountered this and managed to resolve it?  I've had a good Google but turned up nothing.

Thanks in advance,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NH creates and closes connections when it needs them using an `IConnectionProvider`. If every used connection in the application uses the same authentication procedure it would be best to implement your own `IConnectionProvider` and configure it with `MsSqlConfiguration.MsSql2008.Provider<YourOwnConnectionProvider>()`;

```
class MyConnectionProvider : DriverConnectionProvider
{
    public override IDbConnection GetConnection()
    {
        var connection = base.GetConnection();

        byte[] cooky;
        // TODO: authenticate

        return new MyConnectionWrapper(connection, cooky);
    }

    public override void CloseConnection(IDbConnection conn)
    {
        var myConn = conn as MyConnectionWrapper;
        if (myConn != null)
        {
            // TODO: deregister with myConn.Cooky;
        }
        base.CloseConnection(conn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Firo.  I'm curious as to what MyConnectionWrapper implements...  Could you explain the purpose of that class?

Comment: its just a decorator which delegates everything to the underlying connection and holds the cooky as a property to unregister on closing

Comment: It's working!  Many thanks for your help Firo, all I had to do in the end was place the call to setapprole in the GetConnection override and the unsetapprole in the CloseConnection override!

Comment: that was the idea. would you mind to accept the answer if it solves your question?